# HtmlUnit Synchronization Questions

Tags: java, synchronization, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit in one of my web projects to screen scrape some code.  I am wondering to what extent I need to synchronize the code.  Currently I am synchronizing all code where I'm using the WebClient object to retrieve pages (i.e. webClient.getPage(url)).  I assume that if webClient.getPage() is not synchronized, then the 'browser' could possibly try to load multiple pages at once (correct me if I'm wrong).  To get around this, I'd probably have to open multiple windows, correct?

My question is concerning the HtmlPage, HtmlTable, etc. classes.  After I retrieve an HtmlPage object, do I need to synchronize the reading of that page and other objects returned from the HtmlPage object (i.e. HtmlTable), or is the whole page cached into memory?  I assume if it isn't cached, then if the WebClient calls getPage() again while I'm manipulating the previously returned HtmlPage object, bad things could happen.

I'd like to have a Connection class that has synchronized methods controlling calls to the WebClient that will return an HtmlPage and then manipulate the page without having to worry about synchronization.  Are there any issues with this?

Example:

```
public MyConnection {
    private final WebClient webClient;        

    public MyConnection() {
    this.webClient = new WebClient();
    this.webClient.setTimeout(10 * 1000);
    this.webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    this.webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
}

    public synchronized HtmlPage getHtmlPage(String url) {
        return webClient.getPage(url);
    }
}



public UseConnectionClass {
    private MyConnection conn;

    public void getAPage(String url) {
        return conn.getPage(url);
    }        
}

public ClientClass {
    public void doSomething() {
         UseConnectionClass useConn = new UseConnectionClass();
         HtmlPage page1 = useConn.getAPage("http://foobar1.com/");
         HtmlPage page2 = useConn.getAPage("http://foobar2.com/");
         // do something with page1...
         // do something with page2...

        page1.getElementsByTagName("table");
        page2.getElementsByTagName("table");

        // etc...

    }
}
```

EDIT: I know that WebClient is not thread-safe, hence the MyConnection object method getHtmlPage() in my example is synchronized.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads, each using the same WebClient instance?

Comment: Then why would `synchronized` be useful? `synchronized` is used to prevent multiple threads to execute the same code block in parallel. You only have one thread.

Comment: My mistake.  It is a web application so yes, it would be multi-threaded.  The MyConnection object could be called simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the javadoc](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html) says:

> a WebClient instance is not thread safe. It is intended to be used
>   from a single thread.

Each thread should have its own WebClient.

Comment: I already know this from the docs.  I am asking about the objects retrieved from calling the WebClient.  When I get back an HtmlPage from calling the webClient.getPage() method, is the HtmlPage thread safe, or does any method dealing with the HtmlPage objects also need to be synchronized?

Comment: Given that a page is linked to the WebClient used to get it, I would also use it from a single thread: the same thread than the one to which its WebCLient belongs.

Comment: So it looks like any of the objects linked somehow to the WebClient need to be inside of synchronized methods, including the HtmlTables, etc.

Comment: No. It seems like you just shouldn't share them between threads.